# How can you determine image size from a command line?

Tags: images

I want to keep a collection of images (which arrive via RSS) on a shared network drive (for anyone to have SFW desktop backgrounds).

However, some of the images that arrive are absurdly small (85x75, for example).

How can I ensure that all images in the directory are of a minimum size (eg 1366x768)? I want to be able to [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) maintenance on the directory so that too-small images are not kept.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/155083/295286

Comment: have you tried `file XYZ` ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/275502/how-to-get-information-about-an-image-picture-from-the-linux-command-line

Comment: @Archemar I tried that, only gives filetype, that's all

Comment: @Serg, it answers file type if we are talking about jpg, if you launch the command with .png files you will get the image size in the answer.

Comment: @YoMismo right, so this wouldn't be useful if images the OP receives are in different format that png, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `imagemagick` :

```
identify -format "%w×%h\n" foo.png
```

or `graphicsmagick` :

```
gm identify -format "%w×%h" clipart-playback-buttons-d1e5.png
```

(graphicsmagick adds a newline by default)

Those print width×height, e.g. 85×75 or 4328×4278. Identify can show you other information of the image, too.

Comment: this looks like just what I'm looking for - @[Serg](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/85039/serg) mentioned it in a comment off [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/155083/3544), too

Answer (score 1):

You may try whether the picture data contain EXIF Information; in that case you can use `exiftool`, e.g.:

```
$ exiftool -S dscn0986.jpg dscn0986_th.jpg | grep ^Image
ImageWidth: 1024
ImageHeight: 768
ImageSize: 1024x768
ImageWidth: 128
ImageHeight: 128
ImageSize: 128x128
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the system you are running of course. In Linux, you should be able to do 'file ' and see the size in the output which you can then parse and make decisions from.